# How to update an empty paragraph with userinput using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

[This example in jQuery](http://jsbin.com/asale) is what I am looking for in pure JavaScript.

It's an example of a `<textarea>` where a paragraph `<p></p>` is updated as the user types in the textarea.

My question is how can it be done in pure JavaScript?

An attempt on my behalf looks like this but it doesn't quite work:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="textarea">
    <textarea name="myText" id="myText" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <p id="textOuput"></p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('myText');

textArea.onkeyup = function() {
    var val = textArea.value,
    textOutput = document.getElementById('textOutput');
    textOutput.innerHTML = val; // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
};
```

Comment: In addition to Tibos's answer: 1) it's computationally wasteful to re-fetch the element from the DOM for every keypress. Do it once, outside the event callback, instead. 2) No real need to cache the field's value in a variable first, since you read it only once - just refer to it directly.

Comment: @Utkanos

Thanks for your advice. However, I'm not completely sure if I understand you correctly. Do you mean something like this:

    `var textArea = document.getElementById('myText');

        textArea.onkeyup = function() {
        document.getElementById('textOutput').innerHTML = textArea.value;
    };`

Comment: Yes - cache the element once, not on each keypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your id of the paragraph:

```
<p id="textOuput"></p>
```

should be:

```
<p id="textOutput"></p>
```

Adding Utkanos' comments, the JS code could look like this:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById('myText');
var textOutput = document.getElementById('textOutput');
textArea.onkeyup = function() {
    textOutput.innerHTML = textArea.value;
};
```

Comment: Wow.. that one really made me feel like an idiot ;) Thank you! :)